# Apple Mail: display original sender instead of Siri's detected one

Tags: macos, command-line, mail.app, email

I need to change Apple Mail's *Viewing > Use Smart Address* setting via command line, to deploy via MDM.

Apparently, this setting is `AddressDisplayMode` and resides in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist`, but when I try changing it I am denied:

```
$ defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist AddressDisplayMode 3
2023-08-23 09:35:13.373 defaults[18844:227161] Could not write domain /Users/me/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist; exiting
```

Does anyone know how to change this setting via command line, or other means? We use Kandji as MDM.

EDIT: added `ls` output as requested in comments:

```
$ ls -le@O ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist
-rw-------  1 me  staff  - 131 Aug 18 10:13 /Users/me/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist
```

Comment: Can you run `ls -le@O ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist` and add the result to the question?

Comment: Added `ls` output as requested